# how can i put My Sidebar on the right part of the page in angular?

Tags: angular

I am trying to make an angular admin panel but i have a problem i want the sidebar to be on the right part of the page (RTL) but i do not know how to do that ?
this is my side bar html code

```
<div>
<div lang="en" direction="rtl" dir="rtl" style="direction: rtl">
<mat-nav-list >
    <div class="profile-card">
        <div class="header">
            <h2>Personal Account </h2>
            <h4>info</h4>
        </div>
        <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Personal Account ">
    </div>
    <mat-divider></mat-divider>
    <h2 matSubheader>pages</h2>
    <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/" >Dashboard</a>
    <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/posts" >Posts</a>
    <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/articles" >Articales</a>

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>

    <h2 matSubheader >Tools</h2>
    <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/contacts" >
      <mat-icon>import_contacts</mat-icon>
      Contacts
    </a>

    <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/contacts" >
        <mat-icon>contact_phone</mat-icon>
        Leads
    </a>

</mat-nav-list>
</div>
</div>
```

this is my dashboard code

```
<div >
<div>
    Line charts
</div>

<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<div>
    <div>line chart</div>
    <div>line chart</div>
    <div>line chart</div>
    <div>line chart</div>
</div>

<mat-divider></mat-divider>

<div>
    <div>Table</div>
    <div>Pie Charts</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i found the solution about header i used row reverse and it is on the right part

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <mat-toolbar-row fxLayout="row-reverse">

          <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggleSideBar()" >
          <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
        </button>

        <span>panel </span>
        <span fxFlex="1 1"></span>
        <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>settings</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <button mat-icon-button>
            <mat-icon>help_outline</mat-icon>
        </button>

          <button mat-icon-button >
            <mat-icon> 
              <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
            <mat-icon>person_outline</mat-icon>
          </button>
            <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
             <button mat-menu-item>
                <mat-icon>exit_to_app</mat-icon>
                Sign out
             </button>
            </mat-menu></mat-icon>
        </button>

    </mat-toolbar-row>
</mat-toolbar>
```

can you guys please help me i really do not know what to do?

this is a picture 
[image]

Comment: A working example will help, maybe a stackblitz. Or I don't think angular is necessary so you can create a fiddle with your html and css

Comment: @Kenny i add a picture

Answer (score 0):

dir="rtl" will solve the problem but I think you forgot to add flex-layout parameters in your parent div. So put **fxLayout="row"** to your parent div

And the working code should be like

```
<div lang="en"  dir="rtl" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start stretch">
    <mat-nav-list>
        <div class="profile-card">
            <div class="header">
                <h2>Personal Account </h2>
                <h4>info</h4>
            </div>
            <img src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg" alt="Personal Account ">
        </div>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <h2 matSubheader>pages</h2>
        <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/" >Dashboard</a>
        <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/posts" >Posts</a>
        <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/articles" >Articales</a>

        <mat-divider></mat-divider>

        <h2 matSubheader >Tools</h2>
        <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/contacts">
          <mat-icon>import_contacts</mat-icon>Contacts
        </a>
        <a mat-list-item  routerLinkActive="list-item-active" routerLink="/contacts">
            <mat-icon>contact_phone</mat-icon>Leads
        </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
    <div>
        <!-- Put your dashboard content here -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Working stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-icnbwh

Comment: I did this but profile is still on the right part of the page

Comment: i want the personal account be under the panel

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have added a stackblitz into my answer. It works in there. Feel free to edit it and generate your problematic situtation. Then please share it with us to help you.

Comment: i understand what you say but i if you look at the picture in my question you see post works part too i want the place of  personal account and post works to be switched

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but to me, your sidenav code doesn't seem to be from the Angular Material docs.

Here is an example:

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav
    #drawer
    class="sidenav"
    fixedInViewport
    mode="over"
    opened="false"
    position="end"
  >
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item routerLink="">Example</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content>

    <app-topnav (toggle)="drawer.toggle()"></app-topnav>

   <-- App content -->
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

`position: end` on `mat-sidenav` positions the sidenav on the right side.

Comment: i only posted the html part of my code if you see the picture i want it to be an RTL dashboard i mean the personal account that is sidebar to be under the panel

Comment: @nazaninn `position: end` on the mat-sidenav tag is the correct one